# Get only a portion of a line in the source code of a website in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, html

I followed [this video](https://youtu.be/HFM0Wwv021k) in order to get the source code of a site on an android application with Android Studio.

This was the [question](https://iatw.cnaf.infn.it/eee/monitor/) of this site.

I only need to get the 179 line of source code, and only the first part of it (tr class = "green").
So that I can compare it in a if/else statement.

Sorry if I have not expressed correctly but this is my best with English :)

Thanks!

Comment: "Lines" in markup are not well-defined. You'd be much better off using a sensible parser like JSoup.

Comment: You'd be even better off not doing this at all-  this code will be extremely birttle and likely to break constantly as their site evolves.  Either find an API thaey procide for this data, or find another source of info that exports the data you need in a more programmer friendly way

Answer (score 0):

Use a Scanner for this. A scanner works Pretty easily. You can implement a Scanner like this:`Scanner sc = new Scanner(yourInputStream)`. How did you store the data of the Website? Have you declared a String containing the html Code? Otherwise you can just do this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL("your URL").openConnection().getInputStream));
```

The Scanner has different Methods. This would be my Implementation:

```
String result;
while(sc.hasNext){
   String next = sc.next();
   if(next == "the part you Need")
       result = next;
```